# Delete custom options programmatically if more then 1

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, programmatically

I'm adding a custom option (checkbox with 2 rows) programmatically to simple products (10.000+) after a import. All custom option values are the same.

Due to a memory issue it failed the first time (partially) and after setting a higher memory limit some products now have 2 custom options.

Is there a way get the amount of custom options through a collection and  delete any second (or more) custom options so every product has only 1 custom option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just deleted all custom options programmatically by:

```
require_once '../app/Mage.php';
Mage::init();
Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option')->getCollection()->walk('delete');
```

and then run the code for adding custom options programmatically again.